# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sum\limits_{r=1} ^\infty (x)^{\frac{1}{r}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

How do I evaluate the following limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sum\limits_{r=1} ^\infty (x)^{\frac{1}{r}}$$
**note** - I’m high school student

Comment: Are you sure that the sum converges for a given $x>0$? It seems to me that each term converges to 1 as $r\rightarrow +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this hopefully should have been taught in your class. But if $x > 0$, then $\lim_{r\to\infty} x^{1/r} = 1$. Hence this series fails the Divergence Test because the terms of the series to not tend to $0$ at $r\to\infty$.

Comment: I think question is $x^{\frac{1}{r}}$..

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can use Euler–Maclaurin formula to check convergence region and approximate value, $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} x^{\frac{1}{r}} \ \approx \int_1 ^{\infty} x^{\frac{1}{t}} dt$